# RHEL 5 Server running with 8 core. Load is always 0 or 1. but RAM (8GB) always occupied

Tags: memory

I am seeing load is `0` or `1` since a few weeks on my RHEL5 server with 8 cores.
But RAM always fully occupied. I am trying to debug the issue. How can we  diagnose where memory is going?

Comment: How do you check the RAM availability?

Answer (score 2):

In linux, it's normal that RAM is full. See the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:        2051700 kB
MemFree:           74376 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:          1562336 kB
...
```

As you can see in my example output, I have a total of 2GB RAM and only 74MB is free. That's normal. But, see the value of `Cached`: from the [official Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

> ```
>   Cached: in-memory cache for files read from the disk (the
>           pagecache).  Doesn't include SwapCached
> ```

Every newer operating system handles pagecache like this. When you start an application the code and libraries will be loaded into RAM. They stay in RAM until another application needs RAM and no free RAM is available. That's why RAM is always *full*.

If you want to know the amount of RAM that is occupied **and** needed, you have to substract the value of `Cached` and `MemFree` from `Memtotal`, in my case:

```
  2051700 kB
- 1562336 kB
-   74376 kB
-------------
=  414988 kB
```

You see, only 415MB is really needed.